# Notification transport controls dont appear to be doing anything

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I have created an app that can play audio using a MediaBrowserServiceCompat and a MediaSessionCompat. As per the instructions on the android developers website, I have created a notification in the MediaSessionCompat.Callback().onPlay() method that uses MediaStyle to provide transport controls which are supposed to connect to my media session when provided with the appropriate token. The in app controls for playing and pausing work as expected, even when the app is closed and opened again. The service appears to be running as expected.

The problem however, is that although the notification appears as expected, the included pause button is seemingly unable to do anything. And despite the fact that the android developers example indicates that a cancel button should be present, it is not. Furthermore the example also indicated that the service should be stoppable by swiping the notification away, and yet it does not.

Suffice it to say, nothing in the following code snippet is working correctly. Except that the notification does, in fact, appear.

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder getMediaNotificationBuilder() {

        Intent contentIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, contentIntent, 0);

        MediaControllerCompat controller = mMediaSession.getController();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, "PODCAST");

        builder
                .setContentTitle("PODCAST")
                .setContentText("THIS IS A PLACE HOLDER.")
                .setSubText("Still a place holder.")

                // Enable launching the player by clicking the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingContentIntent)

                // Stop the service when the notification is swiped away
                .setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(mContext, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))

                // Make the transport controls visible on the lockscreen
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)

                // Add an app icon and set its accent color
                // Be careful about the color
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))

                // Add a pause button
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause",
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(mContext,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE)))

                // Take advantage of MediaStyle features
                .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0)

                        // Add a cancel button
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setCancelButtonIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(mContext,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)));

        return builder;
    }
```

I then go on to pass this notification to

`startForground(1, getMediaNotificationBuilder().build())`

and then start the service.

I will be happy to share the entire app source code if it is necessary. I am sure that I have missed something very simple here.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected I was missing something very simple. In order for my MediaBrowserServiceCompat subclass to react to my notification controls, I needed to override onStartCommand from the Service base class and pass the Intent there in to my MediaSessionCompat object. After doing this, the MediaSessionCompat.Callback should handle the command assuming it has been programed to do so. This is what the code for that looks like, inside of my MediaBrowserService class.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand(): received intent " + intent.getAction() + " with flags " + flags + " and startId " + startId);
    MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mMediaSession, intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

After adding this code you should see the method in logcat as well. Just in case anyone out there is still missing something, you will at least know that the code is responding to your button presses.

EDIT:

As for stopping the Service by swiping the notification, I was misunderstanding the interaction between the notification and the user. The notification CAN be swiped away by the user but only if the media is PAUSED first. This paradigm is further supported by the standard media player app's notification controls. This makes sense as the user might accidentally swipe away the controls while in the middle of listening to something otherwise.

In addition I have decided to include the entire source code for my MediaBrowserServiceCompat class in hopes that this additional information will
provide some context for disscussion

```
public class MediaPlaybackService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "MediaPlaybackService";
private static final String MY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID = "media_root_id";
private static final String MY_EMPTY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID = "empty_root_id";

// Volume levels: Normal and Duck
// VOLUME_DUCK is the volume we set the media player to when we lose audio focus, but are allowed to reduce the volume instead of stopping playback.
public static final float VOLUME_DUCK = 0.2f;
public static final float VOLUME_NORMAL = 1.0f;

private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession;
private MediaPlayer        mMediaPlayer;

// Current local media player state
private PlaybackStateCompat.Builder mStateBuilder;
private int                         mState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE;

private final class MediaSessionCallback extends MediaSessionCompat.Callback implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener{

    private Context mContext;

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    // Declare the "SHIT THAT'S LOUD" intent, any broadcast receiver
    // that is connected to it will trigger when the headphones come unplugged
    private IntentFilter shitThatsLoudIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
    private BroadcastReceiver shitThatsLoudBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        // TODO: Put me in a separate class
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SHIT THATS LOUD! The headphones have come unplugged!");
        }
    };

    private MediaSessionCallback(Context context) {
        super();

        mContext = context;
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        initMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void initMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://www.blogtalkradio.com/kylekulinski/2018/10/15/the-kyle-kulinski-show.mp3");
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener  (this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener     (this);

            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ".initMediaPlayer(): IOException: "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void mediaPlay() {
        registerReceiver(shitThatsLoudBroadcastReceiver, shitThatsLoudIntentFilter);
        if (mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(getAudioFocusRequest()) == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio focus request granted.");

            mState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING;

            mStateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP);
            mStateBuilder.setState(mState, mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1.0f, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
            mMediaSession.setActive(true);

            mMediaPlayer.start();

            startService(new Intent(mContext, MediaPlaybackService.class));
            startForeground(1, getMediaNotificationBuilder().build());
        }
    }

    private void mediaPause() {

        unregisterReceiver(shitThatsLoudBroadcastReceiver);

        mState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED;

        mStateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP);
        mStateBuilder.setState(mState, mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1.0f, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());

        mMediaPlayer.pause();

        stopForeground(false);

    }

    private void releaseResources() {

        mMediaSession.setActive(false);

        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocusRequest(getAudioFocusRequest());

        unregisterReceiver(shitThatsLoudBroadcastReceiver);

        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

        stopSelf();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder getMediaNotificationBuilder() {

        Intent contentIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, contentIntent, 0);

        MediaControllerCompat controller = mMediaSession.getController();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, "PODCAST");

        builder
                .setContentTitle("PODCAST")
                .setContentText("THIS IS A PLACE HOLDER.")
                .setSubText("Still a place holder.")

                // Enable launching the player by clicking the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingContentIntent)

                // Stop the service when the notification is swiped away
                .setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(mContext, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))

                // Make the transport controls visible on the lockscreen
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)

                // Add an app icon and set its accent color
                // Be careful about the color
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))

                // Add a pause button
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(
                        R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause",
                        MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(mContext,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)))

                // Take advantage of MediaStyle features
                .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0)

                        // Add a cancel button
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setCancelButtonIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(mContext,
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)));

        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        super.onPlay();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "I tried to play music");

        mediaPlay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "I Tried to pause");

        mediaPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseResources();
    }

    private AudioFocusRequest getAudioFocusRequest() {
        // Request audio focus for playback, this registers the afChangeListener
        AudioAttributes attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build();
        AudioFocusRequest audioFocusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
                .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(this)
                .setAudioAttributes(attrs)
                .build();

        return audioFocusRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio focus has been restored after it was transiently arrested by and intrusive app.  We can now start playing audio normally again.");
                mMediaPlayer.setVolume(VOLUME_NORMAL, VOLUME_NORMAL);
                mediaPlay();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio focus was lost flat out. Save what we were doing so we don't forget about it later.");
                mediaPause();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio focus was lost (Transient) but we might get it back later, still stop and save though.");
                mediaPause();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio focus was lost but was just need to keep it down instead of stopping.");
                mMediaPlayer.setVolume(VOLUME_DUCK, VOLUME_DUCK);
                break;

            default:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ignoring unsupported audio focus change: "+focusChange);
                break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MediaSessionCallback.onPrepared(): MediaPlayer is prepared!");
        // The media player is done preparing. That means we can start playing if we
        // have audio focus.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Media player error: what=" + what + ", extra=" + extra);
        return false; // true indicates we handled the error
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Create a MediaSessionCompat
    mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, LOG_TAG);
    // Set the session's token so that client activities can communicate with it.
    setSessionToken(mMediaSession.getSessionToken());
    // MediaSessionCallback() has methods that handle callbacks from a media controller
    mMediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback(this));
    // Enable callbacks from media buttons and transport controls
    mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS
    );

    // Set initial PlaybackState with ACTION_PLAY, so that media buttons start the player
    mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
            );
    mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand(): received intent " + intent.getAction() + " with flags " + flags + " and startId " + startId);
    MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mMediaSession, intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {
    return new BrowserRoot(MY_EMPTY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentMediaId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
    //  Browsing not allowed
    if (TextUtils.equals(MY_EMPTY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID, parentMediaId)) {
        result.sendResult(null);
        return;
    }

    // TODO: If in the future we decide that we do want this class to handle the podcast metadata
    // Then we must adapt what ever data podcastFactory produces into a List of MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem objects
    // The constructor of MediaItem requires that a MediaDescription object be passed to it.
    // MediaDescription has a builder class which contains methods for setting Title, Artist, Uri, etc...

    // MediaDescription.Builder mMediaDescriptionBuilder = new MediaDescription.Builder();

    // mMediaDescriptionBuilder.setTitle(String);
    // mMediaDescriptionBuilder.setMediaUri(String);

    // MediaDescription mMediaDescription = mMediaDescriptionBuilder.build()

    // MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem mMediaItem =
    //     new MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem(
    //          mMediaDescription,
    //          int flags -> FLAG_BROWSABLE and/or FLAG_PLAYABLE
    // );

    // add MediaItem to SomeList

    // result.sendResult(SomeList);
}
```